# What could be a word for this concept?

Tags: single-word-requests, neologisms

I asked this [question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/40897/can-machines-raise-socially-functioning-people) on Stack Worldbuilding:

> In this world a secret society "farms" people with desired features
>   (personality appearances etc.). They have ectogenesis of course; but
>   they can't afford personnel to take care of the "products" until they
>   reach maturity (14-20 years depending on the end uses). What kind of
>   machines/software are needed to raise them in an appropriate way?
>
> Consider that these people will be reintroduced into an already
>   existing society and therefore need not be capable to form a new one
>   on their own. In particular they need at the very least: language,
>   self-care, basic knowledge of science/literature, basic social skills.
>
> I know this is a common tech in works that feature embryo space
>   colonization but I am not aware of any that describe the technology in
>   any useful details.

What could be a word to refer to the concept of being raised by machines?

I am looking for a word with an etymology but even a "slang term" could be interesting. Is it even ok to ask this kind of question here? I read some of your rules but I'm still not sure

Comment: *Machine-bred*, *mech-bred*?

Comment: [What if I told you](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11511/how-do-machines-breed-humans-in-the-matrix), you are in the [matrix](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/matrix-morpheus)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider **cyber-tailored individuals**.

> Examples:
>
> - Processes based on Darwin's Theory of Evolution favour the generation of increasingly tailored individuals.
> - Koopersmith also gave a description of how a political campaign would be  cyber-tailored to voters.

Answer (score 2):

You could run with something such as **engineered inculcation**; Then suppose differing states, such as, pre-inculcation and post-inculcation; Perhaps a process of **algorithmic inculcation** could be quite fitting ... That is quite a macabre world that you are dreaming of, a modern take on eugenics. However, that aside, I have given words that describe a possible process and not the state; Another take on this might be to consider the term "zombie". Often used when describing a similar situation which arises in nature, as one organism is hijacked by another parasite organism. Perhaps you might consider describing a hijacking by mechanism, rather than an organism, is this a possible root for a definition; Could **z-autonomy** or **z-autonomics** fit the bill? **z-autonomies** ...

Comment: what would the "z" mean?

Comment: It is a wink at the 'zombie' aspect that seems somehow apparent when inculcate by an alien mechanism; host to a parasite. Ectogenesis; What a wonderful word, I like the sound of that very much, most fitting.

Answer (score 1):

You might say that such a person was generated or perhaps actualised by machines. So maybe machine-generated or machine-generation.

Comment: seems to refer more to the process of ectogenesis than to being educated by a machine

Answer (score 0):

According to *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003), one meaning of the word **incubator** is

> an apparatus with a chamber used to provide controlled environmental conditions esp. for the cultivation of microorganisms or the care and protection of premature or sick babies

It seems to me that the process you seem to have in mind could be described as "prolonged incubation"—and therefore that the word for people raised by such means might be **incubated**.

Comment: I don't think "care and protection" can really include the concept of  "education"